# NullPointer com.google.android.gms.internal.v$b.a

Tags: android

I am getting this nullpointer report and I have no idea where it is coming from. I searched google but there is no reference to it. Anyone know what causes this error?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.internal.v$b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.do.bc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.en$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.eo$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Affected SDK versions for me:

```
2.3.6 45%   9
4.0.4 35%   7
2.3.4 15%   3
```

Comment: Why have you post an obfuscated code?

Comment: @PozzoApps how am i supposed to find the unobfuscated version for google's code?. edit: i'll email them and ask for their mapping file

Comment: I have 58 entries of this the last week as well so yes Google Play Services is at fault. Not the first time and not the last that they have bugs in that bloated framework.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by AdMob.
upgrade to newer google play service library can solve the problem.